# Send text from a HTML div to a HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to send text from ASP server to a client side DIV and then to a client side textarea.

I cannot send directly from ASP server side to the client side textarea, because if I do that the server crashes/lose server connection.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FromJavaScriptToASP() {
        document.getElementById('<%= JavascriptToAspButton.ClientID %>').click();
        var output = document.getElementById('<%= textdiv.ClientID%>');
        var textarea = document.getElementById("MainTextBox");
        textarea.value = output.value;
    }
</script>
```

When I use this javascript I get a error saying: 
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required"

How can I send text from a HTML div to a HTML textarea?

Answer (score 2):

`div` elements do not have value. You can get their text through `textContent` or `innerText`, or various other ways if you want to consider child elements too for example.

Comment: My div doesn't have textContent or innerText. Closest thing is innerHTML.